# meteor mup: building and deploying programatically

Tags: meteor, mup

I want to set autoscaling for my meteor app.
Ideally I would like to keep build image ready on s3(or some other storage, image would be typically generated from last build) and using aws-lambda(so that no dedicated build server is needed) to deploy using this image on new instance. I would like all this to be finished within 2 minutes.

So is it possible to mup for these tasks

1. build image and save it to aws s3, without deployment.
2. run `mup deploy` programatically using image from aws s3.
3. No need of `mup setup`, because I will launch instance with ami which has already been setup.

mup is also setting up ssl for me using letsencrypt.

I am also open to other tools/scripts to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get much response from this question, because mup makes deployment life quite simple, and most people who use it don't know much about what it does.

You should have a look at the code of meteor-up to see what it does, and see where you can extend it for your own purposes. You could also look at yamup, as that is another approach to the same problem.